# Count occurrences of each word in UTF-8 string

Tags: php, string, utf-8

Am stuck with a problem assigned by my mentor who wants me to write a PHP script which reads a UTF-8 encoded file content and return the number of occurrences of each word as json.

The language of the file content is Russian Cyrillic.

**Here is the Sample text**

```
Он бледен. Мыслит страшный путь.
В его душе живут виденья.
Ударом жизни вбита грудь,
А щеки выпили сомненья.

Клоками сбиты волоса,
Чело высокое в морщинах,
Но ясных грез его краса
Горит в продуманных картинах.

Сидит он в тесном чердаке,
Огарок свечки режет взоры,
А карандаш в его руке
Ведет с ним тайно разговоры.

Он пишет песню грустных дум,
Он ловит сердцем тень былого.
И этот шум… душевный шум…
Снесет он завтра за целковый.
```

As per my research, PHP's predefined string functions can seamlessly handle this problem only under a condition that it must be ASCII encoded. In this case do we have some third party libraries or APIs to handle utf-8 encoded strings of other non English language.

Comment: "PHP's predefined string functions can seamlessly handle this problem only under a condition that it must be ASCII encoded" - There're functions that support Unicode (custom encodings, to be precise), it's just that not all of PHP functions do (they were written before UTF-8 got popular).

Answer (score 2):

Use mb_string functions:

```
<?php

$str = "Он бледен. Мыслит страшный путь.
        В его душе живут виденья.
        Ударом жизни вбита грудь,
        А щеки выпили сомненья.

        Клоками сбиты волоса,
        Чело высокое в морщинах,
        Но ясных грез его краса
        Горит в продуманных картинах.

        Сидит он в тесном чердаке,
        Огарок свечки режет взоры,
        А карандаш в его руке
        Ведет с ним тайно разговоры.

        Он пишет песню грустных дум,
        Он ловит сердцем тень былого.
        И этот шум… душевный шум…
        Снесет он завтра за целковый.";


$words = preg_split('/[ .,-?!:;\'"\n\r]+/', mb_strtolower($str));

$mp = [];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (!mb_strlen($word)) continue;
    
    if (!isset($mp[$word])) {
        $mp[$word] = 0;
    }
    $mp[$word]++;
}

var_dump($mp);
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution splits the text into an array which then contains the words. The regular expression is just an approach and needs improvement. The evaluation is then done with array_count_values.

```
$result = array_count_values(preg_split("~[ ,.;\r\n\t]+~u",$str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

A distinction is made here between upper and lower case.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/5iVnX

If only the first letter of a word is not to be distinguished or if words such as make-up are to be recognized as one word, the code becomes somewhat more extensive.

```
function mb_word_count($string, $mode = MB_CASE_TITLE, $characters = null){
  $string = mb_convert_case($string, $mode, "UTF-8");
  $addChars = $characters ? preg_quote($characters, '~') : "";
  $regEx = "~[^\p{L}0-9".$addChars."]+~u";
  return array_count_values(preg_split($regEx,$string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
}
```

The mb_word_count function returns an array with all words as a key and their number as a value. Artificial words like str2hex are recognized as one word. Only the first letter of a word is not differentiated between upper and lower case (MB_CASE_TITLE). Other modes can be chosen from [mb_convert_case](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php). Additional characters can be defined with $characters, which are then treated like a letter.

Comment: I changed my mind about stealing =))

Comment: I've also edited and expanded my answer again.